# Freefilefillableforms: after fixing rejection errors, will not accept 3rd submission

Tags: taxes, form-1040x, electronic-filing

I e-filed my 2015 return from freefilefillableforms, as I had last year with no problem.

This year my first submission was rejected, and I used the online tool to easily identify and correct the error (missing city in address). I submitted a second time, and got another rejection. Again it was easy to find the error (typo in my SSN).

When I tried to submit a 3rd time, I got the message "The submission is a duplicate of one that was previously received." It shouldn't be a duplicate because the latest version has a different (correct) SSN.

Yet when I check filing status I get "No Record Found - No tax return with this Social Security number and zip code has been transmitted. Please enter your information again."

So now it's not in a rejected state, but I can't file.

Any idea what I can do?

Comment: Well, initial impression is that the site you've mentioned is either a scam or incompetent, given the misbehavior of several links and the complete absence of a way to contact them...

Comment: @keshlam: Don't think it's a scam, as there is an official IRS site - https://www.irs.gov/uac/Before-Starting-Free-File-Fillable-Forms  Now as to incompetent...

Comment: When the trust-e link seems to take one to a page that doesn't actually confirm the site is trustworthy, I'm not sure I'd want to bet on it.

Comment: The site is legit - but you get what you paid for. This site is essentially you filling the forms manually and mailing whatever you filled in. So be thankful that you can get the reject info right away and not to wait for three months before the IRS even talk to you to explain why you haven't gotten your refund...